# Firebase Storage OnsuceessListner in kotlin not showing

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-storage

My addOnSuccessListener is not showing taskSnapshot Override Option,
here is my codes:

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if(requestCode==CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode== Activity.RESULT_OK){

            pdialog.setMessage("Uploading")
            pdialog.show()
            val g = data!!.data
            val hh = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("camera").child("pics"+g.lastPathSegment)
            hh.putFile(g).addOnSuccessListener {  
                pdialog.dismiss()
               Toast.makeText(this,"upload Done",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }.addOnFailureListener {
                Toast.makeText(this,"Error..pls try again",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
        }
    }
```

how do I retrieve images from firebase server ?

Answer (score 0):

The [UploadTask.TaskSnapshot](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/firebase/storage/UploadTask.TaskSnapshot) is available as shown below:

```
 hh.putFile(g).addOnSuccessListener { taskSnapshot ->
    pdialog.dismiss()
    Toast.makeText(this,"upload Done",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

    val uri = taskSnapshot.downloadUrl
 }
```